# C# get count value of type object

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the count value of my list witch is in type object.
This is fictive code for demonstrating what i am working with

```
object test = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
```

This is what i am trying to achive

```
test.count
```

Comment: Why are you using object and why not List<string> lst=new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };

Comment: If you know it's a list but not what type comes into the list, cast it as  `List<object>` and then you should be able to use count

Comment: "This is what i am trying to achive" And what did you try to achieve this? Why do you even store your list into `object`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't fetch a property that isn't known to the type of your variable. You should cast it to the right type:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };

int count = test.Count;
```

If you feel like it, you can use `var`, which will translate to the exact same as above:

```
var /*actually List<string>*/ test = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
```

Comment: Don't you think that it is possible to get count? I mean check my answer. I really want you to judge it.

Comment: @GaurangDave Reflection is serious overkill for a situation like this.

Comment: I know that but I think questioner wants a solution for the sample he put into the question. We should think on that way as well. Then we can advice him not use the code block he gave. What you say?

Comment: No. You should not give bad answers.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, this is the only solution that does what the author needs without any additional information. Therefore, it is the most universal method that works with `object` and does not require any other information.
All arrays and collections, including List, implement the IEnumerable interface, so you can use foreach to iterate over any collection.

```
private static int GetCount(this object val)
{
    if (val is IEnumerable enumerable)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("val is not a valid collection type");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a must for your test to be of object type (which I don't see why it need to be in the question).

Changing

```
object test = new List<string>() {"test1","test2"};
```

to

```
List<string> test = new List <string>() {"test1","test2"};
```

will allow you to use the count method

Comment: `Count` is a property.

Comment: oh yea. Got it confused with Count()

Comment: @PatrickHofman well true, but also properties are technically method + field.

Comment: No, properties are properties. That they translate to something else in CIL doesn't matter for C#.

Comment: @PatrickHofman it will matter in c#, because the methods with the names `int get_Name()/void set_Name(type)` will be reserved by your class and you will not be able to use those names.

Comment: @Stasis There 1 `Count` property and two extension methods `Count` and `LongCount` which will return the number of the elements contained in the `List<T>`. `Count()` method internally checks if your `IEnumerable` implements `ICollection` and if it does it uses the `Count` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your list is string type then you should use string type list instead of object. like below

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
if (lst.Count()  > 0)
{ 
//Do some thing here
}
```

Comment: Using `Count()` here is unnecessary. Use `Count` instead.

Comment: why it is unnecessary?

Comment: Because of the LINQ overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get count of object. You can achieve this using `Reflection`.

```
object test = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };

var property = typeof(ICollection).GetProperty("Count");
int count = (int)property.GetValue(test, null);
```

**NOTE:**

`Reflection` provides  facility to [metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514644/what-exactly-is-metaprogramming). The benefit of  using `Reflection` in **SPECIAL** cases is it gives developers a power to access `Assembly` `Runtime` regardless of any types. I suggest to use Reflection in special scenarios only.

Proper way is to cast `object` to type

```
List<string> test = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };

int count = test.Count;
```

Comment: Using reflection is serious overkill here, very error prone and hard to understand what is the objective. Just give the variable the right type. This answer is bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

Cast object to a particular type while using.

```
object test = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
int count = ((List<string>) test).Count;
```

**OR**

You can simply use var to initialize the list for avoiding casting everytime of usage.

```
var test = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
int count = test.Count;
```

**OR**

You can initialize with a particular type.

```
 List<string> test = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
 int count = test.Count;
```

Answer (score -3):

It will always be the type object when i get it back from my method. I found a solution

```
List<string> tt = (List<string>)test;
myCountValue = tt.Count
```

Comment: if you learn this behavior you will have a lot of confusing code lines in the future :/