# How to avoid exponential increase in code when choosing template arguments at run-time

Tags: c++, oop, templates, interface, generic-programming

Consider a bunch of fundamental types, `Foo`, all with unique implementations of a common method, `Bar()`. I can combine `Foo1`, `Foo2`, `Foo5` like so:

```
CombinedFoo<Foo1, Foo2, Foo5> combined_foo;
```

Which uses recursive inheritance to make `CombinedFoo` effectively the same as:

```
class CombinedFoo <Foo1, Foo2, Foo5>
{
    Foo1 foo1;
    Foo2 foo2;
    Foo5 foo5;

public:

    void Bar ()
    {
        foo1.Bar();
        foo2.Bar();
        foo5.Bar();
    }
};
```

This is handy, but I run into a problem when I want to choose at run-time which `Foo` types to combine (into a single object) to send to function, say:

```
template <typename Foo> void Do (Foo && foo);
```

An example solution with `if`s and `switch`s to solve the 3 option version:

```
int result = 0;

if (criteria_for_foo1)
    result += 100;

if (criteria_for_foo2)
    result += 10;

if (criteria_for_foo3)
    result += 1;

switch (result)
{
     case 001 : Do(Foo3());
                  break;

     case 010 : Do(Foo2());
                  break;

     case 011 : Do(CombinedFoo<Foo2, Foo3>());
                  break;

     case 100 : Do(Foo1());
                  break;

     case 101 : Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1, Foo3>());
                  break;

     case 110 : Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1, Foo2>());
                  break;

     case 111 : Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1, Foo2, Foo3>());
                  break;

     default : break; 
}
```

The `if` statements are fine, they grow linearly, but the `switch` statement grows exponentially as we have more choices. My real-world problem has 4 options and so I need to handle 16 cases that I'd rather not have to maintain.

I believe  that there's no way to avoid the executable from growing exponentially, but is there a way to avoid this in the c++ code (**without introducing significant inefficiencies in the `Bar` method**)? Or is there a known work-around / alternative for this  generic problem?

**EDIT:**

For clarity: `Do(Foo1); Do(Foo2)` is not the same as `Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1, Foo2>())`, and it's crucial that the `Foo`s are combined for a single call to `Do`.

For those who wanting to know the real-world motivation: it's for an optimisation problem, where my `Foo`s are really `Generator`s of fundamental `Move`s that can edit my solution, this is then sent into various heuristics. If I was to send in just one `Generator` at a time then my solvers would be repeating the same type of move thousands of times, and so invariably being unproductive / stuck at local minima (considering the same type of move repeatedly is well known to have this effect).

The reason I select some of these template parameters at run-time is because some `Move`s aren't appropriate for certain problem instances (which my program doesn't become aware of till run-time).

Comment: Do you really need that wrapper? Isn't it just the same as `if(criteria_for_foo1) Foo1() if(criteria_for_foo2) Foo2() ...`

Comment: unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @churill, I can't say that there isn't a better want to do it, but needless to say `Do(Foo1); Do(Foo2);` is not the same as different `Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1, Foo2>())`. So no, sadly you can't simplify it the way that you describe.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom, it's the generic problem that I describe. If I give you a real-world example, expect to be bogged down in a lot of unnecessary information. This seems like a generic design pattern problem that others more experienced than me may have encountered before.

Comment: Does `CombinedFoo` do anything different than calling some method on instances of every type? Maybe use a tuple? As another idea: _"unique implementations of common method"_ sounds like you could do something with interfaces to make it all more generic. But maybe you could clarify _why_ you need `CombinedFoo` in the first place.

Comment: @churill, thanks for your comment. I've edited to give an explanation of the real-world problem, and hopefully it's pretty clear now.

Comment: You say you want to choose "at run time", and you exclude solutions with "run time" in them (virtual functions) - so I'm not sure you can solve the problem in the terms you give. Either you choose for a static solution at compile-time -- and you might have to help the compiler indeed with a combinatorial explosion if combinations between your objects are not trivial -- or you must accept that there is a run time performance hit (because you want a run time solution). Have you done some perf testing? As always, "early optimization is the root of all evil" :)

Comment: @Mic, Thanks for your comment. I accept that there may be no better solution, however, the one that I've given is an example of one that works efficiently at runtime. My real-world version of the Bar method (for each of the fundamental Foos) is itself a one-line function call, so inlining is pretty essential for speed here (and yeah, I've been performance testing). This pattern occurs throughout my code a lot, and has made my code hyperflexible / easy to maintain, but the small snippets of code in each function makes inlining crucial to my speeds.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Long time since I did some metaprogramming, but it seems to me it could help here. Maybe look in the [Boost.Hana direction](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html). You would have a fixed set of `Foo1, Foo2..., FooN` templates, and decide on which to choose based on the bitfield flag you build at runtime. Not sure it works because of the static/dynamic duality here, but looking at Hana might give some insight or tradeoff to pick from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Generic way to choose types from any type list at run-time:

Here's the interface:

```
template <typename ... Types, typename Functor>
void ChooseTypes (const bool chosen[], Functor && f)
```

Where `chosen[0] = true` signals choosing the first type from the list.

Internally the types are forwarded to the functor like so: `f()<ChosenTypes...>()` with ordering maintained.

---

### How to use:

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    // data/references can be stored/passed here

    template <typename ... Ts>
    void operator () ()
    {
        // Ts = the chosen types

        // Here's where we get to use them...
    }
};

// later in func/method:

bool chosen[5];

// choose which types you want

MyFunctor f;

// pass data in the functor
// (const/& by constructor)

// Then this will call the functor with the chosen types:
ChooseTypes<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(chosen, f);
```

---

### Library code:

```
namespace ChooseTypesRecursive // internal use only
{

// CTR = ChooseTypesRecursive

template <int N, typename Functor>
struct CTR
{
    using Next = CTR<N-1, Functor>;

    template <typename CandidateType, typename ... Args>
    static void Ctr (const bool * chosen, Functor & f)
    {
        if (*chosen)
        {
            Next::template Ctr<Args..., CandidateType>
                (++chosen, f);
        }       
        else
        {
            Next::template Ctr<Args...>
                (++chosen, f);
        }
    }
};

template <typename Functor>
struct CTR <0, Functor>
{
    template <typename ... ChosenTypes>
    static void Ctr (const bool *, Functor & f)
    {
        f.template operator()<ChosenTypes...>();
    }
};

} // namespace ChooseTypesRecursive

template <typename ... Types, typename Functor>
void ChooseTypes (const bool chosen[], Functor && f)
{
    constexpr int N = sizeof...(Types);

    using namespace ChooseTypesRecursive;
    
    CTR<N, Functor>::template Ctr<Types...>(chosen, f);
}
```

---

### Solving the specific question:

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7jso36e9q)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is what you need, but what about this:

```
Foo *obj1 = nullptr;
Foo *obj2 = nullptr;
Foo *obj3 = nullptr;
Foo *obj4 = nullptr;

     if (cond1) { obj1 = new Foo1; /* do more stuff here */ }
else if (cond2) { obj2 = new Foo5; /* do more stuff here */ }
else if (cond3) { obj4 = new Foo5; /* do more stuff here */ }
else            { obj3 = new Foo3; /* do more stuff here */ }
```

Then, call this function:

```
void func(
    Foo *obj1,
    Foo *obj2,
    Foo *obj3,
    Foo *obj4)
{
    if (obj1) obj1->bar();
    if (obj2) obj2->bar();
    if (obj3) obj3->bar();
    if (obj4) obj4->bar();
}
```

Comment: +1 because this strictly answers the question, and makes it obvious that I should've mentioned that the problem is performance-critical. Apologies for that.

Comment: (by the way, you would have to wrap this up into a functoid in order for this to work correctly with `Do`, but this could easily be done with recursive inheritance like the implementation for `CombinedFoo`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
struct DisabledFoo
{
    void Bar() {}
};

template <
    size_t Combination,
    typename Disabled,
    typename... Foos,
    size_t... Is
>
auto FoosFor(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return CombinedFoo<
        std::conditional_t<
            static_cast<bool>(Combination & 1 << (sizeof...(Foos) - 1 - Is)),
            Foos,
            Disabled
        >...
    >{};
}

template <
    typename F,
    size_t Combination,
    typename Disabled,
    typename... Foos
>
void FooDo(const F& func) {
    func(
        FoosFor<
            Combination,
            Disabled,
            Foos...
        >(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Foos)>())
    );
}

template <
    typename F,
    typename Disabled,
    typename... Foos,
    size_t... Combinations
>
constexpr auto MakeFooDoers(std::index_sequence<Combinations...>) {
    return std::array{ FooDo<F, Combinations, Disabled, Foos...>... };
}

constexpr size_t constexpr_pow(size_t base, size_t exp)
{
    size_t ret = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < exp; ++i) {
        ret *= base;
    }
    return ret;
}

template <
    typename F,
    typename Disabled,
    typename... Foos
>
constexpr std::array FooDoers{
    MakeFooDoers<
        F,
        Disabled,
        Foos...
    >(std::make_index_sequence<constexpr_pow(2, sizeof...(Foos))>())
};

template <typename F>
constexpr void DoCombination(size_t combination, const F& func) {
    FooDoers<
        F,
        DisabledFoo,
        Foo1,
        Foo2,
        Foo3
    >[combination](func);
}
```

Call it as

```
DoCombination(0b111, [](auto foo) { Do(foo); });
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45498e1f0110ce33)

This avoids about as much runtime overhead as possible, doing only a single indirect call.  It works by building a `constexpr` array of function pointers, each of which dispatches to a different `CombinedFoo`, where a dummy implementation `DisabledFoo` is used for the Foos we don't actually want to invoke.

Essentially, `FooDoers` ends up looking something like this:

```
constexpr std::array FooDoers = {
    [] { Do(CombinedFoo<DisabledFoo, DisabledFoo, DisabledFoo>{}); },
    [] { Do(CombinedFoo<DisabledFoo, DisabledFoo, Foo3>{});        },
    [] { Do(CombinedFoo<DisabledFoo, Foo2,        DisabledFoo>{}); },
    [] { Do(CombinedFoo<DisabledFoo, Foo2,        Foo3>{});        },
    [] { Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1,        DisabledFoo, DisabledFoo>{}); },
    [] { Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1,        DisabledFoo, Foo3>{});        },
    [] { Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1,        Foo2,        DisabledFoo>{}); },
    [] { Do(CombinedFoo<Foo1,        Foo2,        Foo3>{});        }
};
```

We then index into it and call the correct wrapper.

To add another `Foo` class, just add it as another parameter to `FooDoers` in `DoCombination`.