# Generic Method is not working

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to use this method but I get an error in Eclipse saying the type argument is incorrect and it tells me to change the method signature.  Any reason why?

```
/**Creates an independent copy(clone) of the T array.
 * @param array The 2D array to be cloned.
 * @return An independent 'deep' structure clone of the array.
 */
public static <T> T[][] clone2DArray(T[][] array) {
    int rows=array.length ;

    //clone the 'shallow' structure of array
    T[][] newArray = array.clone();

    //clone the 'deep' structure of array
    for(int row=0;row<rows;row++){
        newArray[row]=array[row].clone();
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're invoking the method?

Comment: tell us how you use it.. as it stands, there are no errors

Comment: Are you using primitives in the calling code?

Comment: This is how I am calling the methodd ArraysUtilities.clone2DArray(grid);

Comment: This is how grid is declared: Gridable[][] grid = new Gridable[row][col];

Comment: OK fixed, it was actually a problem with my call, not the method so sorry about that.  I had to call grid.gird not gird.  I will change the variable name right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `copy2DArray` method you posted appears to work as advertised. Perhaps you are calling the method incorrectly? Also make sure you are not using primitive types instead of objects in the array you are copying. In other words, use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Here is an example of the working method:

```
public class Main {

    // ...
    // Your copy2DArray method goes here
    // ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The array to copy
        Integer array[][] = {
            {0, 1, 2},
            {3, 4, 5},
            {6, 7, 8}
        };

        // Create a copy of the array
        Integer copy[][] = clone2DArray(array);

        // Print the copy of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < copy[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(copy[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This code will print:

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8
```

Comment: Hi, I am not using Primative types and it is still not working.  I am using an Interface I have made called Gridable

Answer (score 1):

It works with all classes. It doesn't work with primitives (`int`, `long`, etc.)

So instead of using primitive arrays use the wrapper classes: use `Integer[][]` instead of `int[][]`.

You can use commons-lang [`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(..)` and `ArrayUtils.toObject(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) to convert arrays between primitives and their wrappers.

Comment: This is because a generic type must extend `Object` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112320/is-static-metaprogramming-possible-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You may be using primitive types, when there's no erasure for primitive types. i.e., int.class is completely impossible, but Integer.class works. Wherever generics are involved, primitive types are a no-go.